# How to print an address of [x][y] element in 2D char array? (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
char arr[2][6] = { "hello", "foo" };

cout << arr[0] << " or " << *(arr) << endl;// prints "hello"
cout << arr[1] << " or " << *(arr + 1) << endl; // prints "foo"

cout << arr << endl; // prints an address of "hello" (and 'h')
cout << arr + 1 << endl; //prints an address of "foo" (and 'f')

cout << arr[0][1] << endl; // prints 'e'
cout << &arr[0][1] << endl; // prints "ello"
```

So, I'd like to print an address of, say, 'e' in "hello". How do I do that?

I know if I was dealing with an array of any other type, **&arr[0][1]** would do the job, however with all of this *cout char(array) overloads* I'm not sure if it's even possible?

Comment: did you try to print a naked `char*`? The issue is the same when you dont have arrays

Comment: Obligatory question: Why are you using a 2 dimensional `char` array instead of a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: ...btw not trying to be snarky but rather suggesting that you can reduce the problem by 2 dimensions and the solution would still be the same.

Comment: There is a overload for `operator <<(std::ostream&, const char*)` which prints c-string (nul-terminated string), you have to cast to `void*` to print address in such case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only by bypassing the IOstream special handling for `char*` (which assumes a C-string and formats its output accordingly):

```
cout << (void*)&arr[0][1] << endl;
//      ^^^^^^^
```

---

This really has nothing to do with 2D arrays. Here's a much simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* str = "hi";
    std::cout << &str[0]        << '\n'; // "hi"
    std::cout << (void*)&str[0] << '\n'; // some address
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b8481ea83cfe349))

Comment: That's it, thanks! I've already tried casting to void*, but without "&" so it didn't work. Care to explain why I need "&"?

Comment: because as you should know, indexing with `str[0]` gets you a reference to a `char`, but you don't want that: you want a pointer, which is what `&` does.

Comment: @EmJov: Because if you want an address you will need the _address-of_ operator, or `&`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the builtin (i.e. non-overloaded) `x[i]` is exactly identical to `*(x+i)`, so `&x[i]` is equivalent to `x+i`. However, `&x[i]` is more clear in its intent and also works in the presence of overloaded `operator[]`.

Comment: True but a story for another day IMO

Comment: Actually, I'm now stuck wondering how come `(void*)(arr[0] + 1)` equals address of `e` and `&arr[0] + 1 ` address of `f`? @Max @Lightness

Comment: `arr[0]` is a `char*` so incrementing it advances to the second char in the array. Casting to void gives you that address.  
`&arr[0]` is a pointer to a `char[6]`, so incrementing it by one moves to the beginning of the next `char[6]` array in `arr`. Here is a playground: https://godbolt.org/g/ahCo78

Comment: @EmJov: Because types. Which book are you using?

Answer (score 5):

There is a overload for `operator <<(std::ostream&, const char*)` which prints c-string (nul-terminated string). You have to cast to `void*` to print address in such case:

```
std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(&arr[0][1]) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The address of 'ello' and 'e' in 'hello' are the same. An array is just a sequential chunk of memory and its address is the address of its first value, that's why the array 'ello' has the same address as 'e'.